# Why is this time complexity O(n)?

Tags: complexity-theory

Why does the below function have a time complexity of O(n)? I can't figure it out for the life of me.

```
void setUpperTriangular (
    int intMatrix[0,…,n-1][0,…,n-1]) {
        for (int i=1; i<n; i++) {
            for (int j=0; j<i; j++) {
                    intMatrix[i][j] = 0;
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

I keep getting the final time complexity as O(n^2) because:

```
i: execute n times{//Time complexity=n*(n*1)
    j: execute n times{ //Time complexity=n*1
        intMatrix[i][j] = 0; //Time complexity=1
    }
}
```

Comment: It's O(n^2), who told you that it's O(n)?

Comment: My professor @Ph.Voronov

Comment: your professor is wrong!

Comment: Your logic is correct, and this is a really trivial example of time complexity. Hopefully just a typo on the professor's part.

Comment: If your professor can't figure this out, I'd be getting worried.

Comment: Her philosophy is this. 
The input size is run n^2 times because it is a 2-dimensional array. Using a dummy variable, we can conclude s = n^2 : n = sqrt(s). Now, the actual nested loops iterate s^2 times. So, the end time complexity is O(s^2). Since n = sqrt(s), and plugging in s^2 for s, you get n = s = O(n).

Comment: @J.Woodring It still goes through half a square matrix so it can't be lower than n^2/2

Comment: @J.Woodring whoopie - by her logic I'm just going to redefine `s = log(n)` and make an `O(log(s))` sort algorithm!  [caveat: actual answer might be something else - this was a guess]

Comment: If n grows by one, does the runtime increase linearly? No, because it's an n x n matrix. So the runtime can't be O(n).

Comment: @Alnitak You lack vision, I'm going to set `s = -1` and create the first algorithm which finishes before it starts.

Comment: @J.Woodring "Now, the actual nested loops iterate s^2 times" why? What is role of s? Honestly, i can't understand her "logic")

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The code iterates through `n^2/2` (half a square matrix) locations in the array, so its time complexity is `O(n^2)`

Answer (score 1):

This is same as insertion sort's for loop. Time complexity of insertion sort is O(n2).

Answer (score 0):

So, CS department head explained it a different way. He said that since the second loop doesn't iterate n times, it iterates n! times. So technically it is O(n).

Comment: what? does n! mean factorial? the 2nd loop iterates n(n-1)/2 times total, it has "i" iterations at each iteration of 1st loop.

Comment: Yes that means factorial

Comment: it does't iterate "n!" times!!)

Comment: This is just wrong, there's no factorial here at all. Also, n! is larger than n so it would be n times n! somehow??

Comment: @J.Woodring please name and shame (the Uni, not the Professor)

Comment: @Alnitak University of West Georgia

Answer (score 0):

It can be at most considered as O(n.m) which finally comes down to O(n.n) or O(n^2)..